# Select the first row of a column in a group of rows within another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to display a list of the first row of a column within a group of rows within another column

**Basic Query:**

> SELECT *  FROM Table_Example cxp

**My Table**

```
    |plan   |code   |des   |month   |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 150B  | Alpha | etc.a| 1      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 150B  | Beta  | etc.b| 2      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Alpha | etc.a| 6      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Alpha | etc.a| 7      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 3      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 7      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 9      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 2      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Gama  | etc.c| 4      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Gama  | etc.c| 12     |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Delta | etc.d| 22     |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 42F   | Alpha | etc.a| 15     |
```

**Expected Result**

```
    |plan   |code   |des   |month   |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Alpha | etc.a| 6      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 3      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Gama  | etc.g| 4      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Delta | etc.d| 22     |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
```

**Transcript Result:** Having the variable '@plan', only show the rows that match that value (example: if '@plan' is 2600C) and within that group of rows, only show the first row of each different 'code' value

**What i tried to do**

> SELECT * FROM Table_Example cxp  WHERE plan = '2600C'

```
    |plan   |code   |des   |month   |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Alpha | etc.a| 6      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Alpha | etc.a| 7      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 3      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 7      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 9      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Beta  | etc.b| 2      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Gama  | etc.c| 4      |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Gama  | etc.c| 12     |
----+-------+-------+------+--------+
    | 2600C | Delta | etc.d| 22     |
```

*But i can't get only the first row of each different 'code'
I was thinking in a SubQuery but i tried a lot of them and i cant get the correct result
or it returns only the 'code' column without the other columns like:*

```
|code   |
+-------+
| Alpha |     
+-------+
| Beta  |       
+-------+
| Gama  |      
+-------+
| Delta |      
+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
  SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by code order by month) as rnk
  FROM Table_Example cxp
  WHERE plan = '2600C'
)A where rnk=1
```